# React app stuck on "Starting the development server"

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have a react app created by create-react-app. After running npm start (the start script is present in package.json as "start": "react-scripts start") the console says Starting the development server as usual and fires up the browser. But after this both the console and the browser do absolutely nothing indefinitely. No error or output. It simply does nothing.

Comment: Strange. Is it every time when you create a new project using create-react-app?

Comment: can you share the screen shot of the terminal, check whether any applicaiton is running in port 3000, may be that can be the issue (guess !!), in the terminaly it will be asking for to press yes or no to open the application in another port.

Comment: Please share the error screenshot

Comment: Yes every time I start the app it starts on a new port. This happens because a Node app remians running on the port that I ran it on. I stop the app using CTRL+C which closes it in the terminal but task manager shows processes still running. I tried killing these processes from task manager and from terminal using taskkill  but both fail. The latter gives error saying "There is no running instance of this process." Starting the app again prompts me to use a different port (3000, 3001, 3002, etc..) which I responed to with yes but again I come to a stop at the "Starting the development server"

Comment: I would share screenshots but there's literally nothing to show. The terminal will not scroll back up from "Starting the development server" and the browser only keeps loading indefinitely.

Comment: After a few exhausting hours spent to no avail I went ahead and resetted my entire PC (it's relatively new so wasn't a hassle). Even uninstalling Node and reinstalling it did not solve this. The zombie processes running on ports 3000 and others remained even after uninstall but cleared out on rebooting the PC.

Comment: can you upload your 
i. package.json file contents  
ii. what version of node you are using
iii. OS 
iv. and If it belongs to any organization( which may have put port permissions) or is it your personal system.

Comment: Which OS and IDE you use?

Comment: You should log the error or try to find more information here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues. 
I think you need to specify more information, like package.json file, or console errors.

Comment: Try to update npm,then react-scripts would get updated. it worked for me.

Comment: You can use `lsof -i :3000` to see what is listening on port 3000. If it is a node.js process, you can also do `killall node` to end all node.js processes.

Comment: Restarting the machine worked for me.

Comment: The "working answer" is "just wait". It happens sometimes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have something similar happening to me.

I have a react project that I want to convert to Typescript and I started as you noted with the "create-react-app", added all my files and hoped for the best - but got stuck like you on the “Starting the development server” message.

I have an 8GB Ram with Windows 10 and once I used the default "npm start" for the first time I've seen the node process uses a lot of memory - So I tried to give it more and at the same time I tired to change the port react uses.

1. Added this to the start script in package.json:

   `"scripts": {
       "start": "PORT=3001 react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8128 start",
       ...
      }`
2. Closed all my chrome browsers (they take pretty much memory)
3. And gave it around 1 minute to run

After 1 minute it started working and from that point it just starts quickly and not uses as much memory and not depended on the port I choose

In my case - I guess the first time you run "npm start" on the React Typescript project it probably index the files (or does something similar - I'm not sure and probably need to read about it - I'm new to typescript) which take a lot of memory.

In your case - It might be something similar

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Closing Chrome browser was all it took for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

First time you run the command it takes about 5 minutes before the page loads.

Comment: Yep, this. Also happened to me on an existing project that I hadn't touched for a few weeks.

Comment: Same happened to me after I performed `npx update-browserslist-db@latest`

Comment: Do we know WHY it takes longer on the first run? Is it indexing files or downloading something?

Comment: I have an issue where it runs for 5 minutes every time on our pipeline, and I'm wondering if it's because of this issue - everytime is treated as the first. Can I save/cache any other files to make this faster later?

Answer (score 8):

Check these two points

1. Run `npm install` command before you start the server.

Then if it is still not running, please try the second command

2. Remove the node modules and run `npm install` once again.

If these two points didn't work, please provide a screenshot for further analysis.

Comment: I tried both methods and both failed me which led me here :(  Another point to be noted is that the package contained few dependencies that had vulnerabilities. Could this be a reason? The "npm install" too hangs sometimes but after trying multiple times it works eventually. The usual hang points are "sill install executeActions" and "postinstall: verb lock using <path to npm cache>"

Comment: @kenneth-rebello provide the screenshots while you run the NPM start comment. If you create a app using create-react-app , packages installed by this command will not have any vulnerabilities. Did you tried to install any packages ??

Comment: Having the same issue and tried this on a fresh clone and still no luck.

Comment: I also noticed that npm build hangs as well. This would suggest that compilation is the issue. However I see nothing in the console or in the npm logs. Don't know where to go from here without anything to go on.

Comment: I tried your method several times but it was failed.

Answer (score 4):

I created my react app by create-react-app too.

I've tried all the method mentioned above. But it didn't work for me.

**Then I accidentally found out if you have unused `import` or any unused statements. You will stuck.**

My react version is `17.0.1`.

Comment: This is a issue with react-scripts itself, they need to fix it. Something related to eslint.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I restarted my macbook, changed nothing and everything worked again ‍♂️

Comment: same. Bonkers that "turn it off and on again" is the best solution to this :-)

Comment: Did the same on windows, worked after restart but can't fix on iMac(((

Comment: I moved to NX - https://nx.dev/getting-started/tutorials/react-standalone-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your dependencies in `package.json` includes the following:

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-scripts": "3.3.0"
```

And scripts to be:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Once you ensure that, you can follow the following steps:

```
1. npm install
2. npm run build
3. npm start
```

Hope will works for you.

Answer (score 1):

the same problem as i met; `npm start` but got stuck like you on the “Starting the development server” message.
after i trying the following ways but didn't worked:

1. npm install
2. npm run build
3. npm start

it seems not the version matter.

finally, i recheck my code, and found the mistake that's the cause of development server fail to start:

```
useEffect()
```

this is the hook incorrect using, maybe i forgot to finish it; then i fixed it, and npm run start, it worked, server started successfully.

Comment: you are right, but it keeps showing in terminal we are missing dependency so add it inside [] and if we do so we call useEffect for infinite times , is there any good way ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this. For me the issue lay in my webpack configuration. I had a webpack alias in there whose alias name was the same as the name of my npm package.

i.e. 
My `package.json` had the following at top.

`"name": "@mycompany/react-common-components"`

Within my `webpack.config.js` I had

```
alias: {
        '@mycompany/react-common-components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
      },
```

Once I changed the webpack alias to the following everything worked fine

```
alias: {
        'react-common-components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue,
I had to build it first

`npm build`
then
`npm start`

I was running react on my Mac and had to give permission for the terminal to interact with chrome before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is my react version:
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",

My node version is 12.18.1, and it didn't work.
I try to change the version to 14.15.0, and then run success.

Comment: Please do not post this as an answer to another person's question, but as your own question. Nobody will be able to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the name of the parent directory. For some reason it choked on "#" when I tried to install into a directory named "#TEMP". Switched to another directory with success.

This has previously worked on my old MBP i9, I'm now on a MBP M1 Monterey 12.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Running lint can also give you hints (often caused by html tags not closed, etc.):

`npm run lint`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a useEffect in App.js, try removing that once, it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you may have some issues with Node and npm.
I would recommend checking the versions first - you’ll need to have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine, and update if needed. It could worth trying to reinstall node.

Checking into node logs could provide some clues on your issue (more information on how to log [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/intermediate/how-to-log/))

Answer (score -1):

I was also having the same issue. Try installing a previous version of react-scripts.

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue was that I had **`.css`** files.

I renamed my css files to **`.scss`** and it works.

For some reason create-react-app chokes on CSS files for me.

Weird.

Answer (score -1):

My team also faced this same issue but we managed to solve it.

- Run `npm install` to update packages
- then run `npm audit fix` to fix vulnerabilities
- Finally close all browser tab to free up RAM. I have seen node processes take a significant amount of memory.
- Run `npm start` and the development server spins up within a minute or two.

---

**NOTE**

Make sure that your dependencies in `package.json` includes the following:

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-scripts": "3.3.0"
```

And scripts to be:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Once you ensure that, you can follow the steps given above.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue. In my case, there was an `.eslintcache` file that had incorrect information in it, and was causing an issue. Simply deleting the file solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was because of using `StrictMode`, the server starts, but the app keeps loading for a long period.

Answer (score -1):

Here are tow points checked:

1. Remove `package.lock` and `node_modules`, re-install: `npm i`.
2. Check the node version. Maybe you currently use version is 12.0.0, but this project limited 14.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue. I just opened chrome to check if it's actually running on there (chrome is my default browser for vs code) and npm could then run the next step after that. So try opening the browser if you're stuck on "starting dev...."

Answer (score -1):

this error can occur because of multiple reasons , my particular case (as shown in the picture attached) occurred abruptly when I was installing splide and styled-components probably because of some vulnerabilities
My error was resolved by running
`npm audit fix --force`